# How can I install the MetaMask extension in Electron?

Tags: electron, ethereum, metamask

I've successfully installed the extension from https://github.com/aragon/metamask-plugin

When the Electron app is started I can see the MetaMask plugin loaded, but can't do much with it. There are some errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: global._runtime.onConnect is not a function
    at Object.connect (blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:139)
    at setupStreams (blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:216)
    at Object.<anonymous> (blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:187)
    at Object.3../lib/extension (blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:265)
    at s (blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:1)
    at e (blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:1)
    at blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:1
connect @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:139
setupStreams @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:216
(anonymous) @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:187
3../lib/extension @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:265
s @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:1
e @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:1
(anonymous) @ blob:file:///c13a5138-3758-47ae-a481-a163d7aa6a19:1
```

And

```
App.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: window._setupMetaMaskPageStream is not a function
    at onMetaMaskLoad (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:1081:14)
    at onMetaMaskLoad (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:19790:30)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js?:69:16)
    at executeDispatch (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js?:85:21)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginUtils.js?:108:5)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:43:22)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:54:10)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/forEachAccumulated.js?:24:9)
    at Object.processEventQueue (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/lib/EventPluginHub.js?:254:7)
```

Comment: Hey! I'm having the problem. did you figure it out ? If so could you please post the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Similar error but I'm using the plugin from the chrome store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those errors are function scope binding errors. The functions `this.setupMetaMaskPageStream` and `this._runtime.onConnect` are called from within the MetaMaskController from other functions, but they seem to be getting called without preserving the scope of the MetaMask controller, defaulting to the global context (hence `window._setupMetaMaskPageStream`).

Without seeing your code, it's hard to know how you called these methods with the wrong context, but it probably involves the `bind` or `call` functions.